# Non-singular-non-redundent representation of rotations and scaling in 3 dimensions

Tags: group-theory, geometry

First, lets pin down what *singularities* mean.
We define two mappings of vectors $M$ and $N$ as *close* if 
$|M(v)-N(v)|\le\epsilon|v|$ for all $v$ (at least for linear mappings).
We define two representations (which are vectors) $r(M)$ as *close* if 
$|r(M)-r(N)|\le\epsilon$.
We define *far* mappings: $|M(v)-N(v)|>E|v|$, $E>>\epsilon$, for some $v$.
Far representations: $|r(M)-r(N)|>E$, $E>>\epsilon$.

We face two types of coordinate singularities:

1. *Forward* in which $r(M)$ and $r(N)$ are close, but $M$ and $N$ are far (i.e. Eular angles and gimbal lock).
2. *Backward*, in which $r(M)$ and $r(N)$ are far, but $M$ and $N$ are close (i.e. poles in a latitude-longitude system [although this isn't a mapping]).

In 2-D, you can represent rotation+scaling as a 2-D vector: The length is the scale and the direction is the angle. There are no singularities if you represent it in Cartesian format.

In 3-D, you almost can do a trick with quaternions, in which their length is the scale (no longer unit quaternions). However, you miss negative lengths. In 2-D, negative lengths are just 180 degree rotations, but in 3-D, they reflect. Fortunately, two opposite quaternions are equivalent, so it makes sense to assign one to a positive length, and one negative. However, this fails because there is no way to break quaternions up without introducing "branch lines".

Is there another way without introducing another degree of freedom?

Edit: We allow double coverings!

Answer (score 0):

It's just a long shot, but it seems to me that it could have something to do with the [Hairy ball theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairy_ball_theorem).

Let's consider the unit sphere and assign to each point $x$ the rotation $R_x$ from $(1,0,0)$ to that point. Then assign to each point a tangent vector corresponding to the gradient
of $|r(R_x)|$. By the Hairy ball theorem, there will be a point where the gradient is 0, which means there is a singularity - around this point the representation changes infinitesimally little.